# Организация поиска?

Tags: orm, kohana, php

Я не знаю недочет ли это `ORM`, но задача такая: Есть два поля, напр. `name` и `surname`, как  организовать поиск по одному из полей или сразу по двум?

стандартно это все в `ORM` ищется как

```
$user = ORM::factory('user')->where('name','=',$username)->find();
```

А что делать если юзер вбил в поле поиска и имя и фамилию? Ставить каждый раз `if`-ы накладно, может быть больше 2-х полей, как в таком случае быть?

`update`

два поля поиска:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="Alex" />
<input type="text" name="surname" value="" />
```

Ситуации могут быть разные, оба поля заполнены, оба пусты, одно из них заполнено. Как с этим быть в Моделе, т.е. как сделать выборку используя `ORM`?

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**

Оказалось не все так просто, в общем дело такое, есть модель объекта, в нем есть метод, который ищет все объекты, по определенным фильтрам:

```
class Model_Object extends ORM {

public function get_objects($filters = array())
{

        if (!empty($filters['Role']))
               $role = $filters['Role'];
          else
        $role = NULL;

        $objects = ORM::factory('object')
                           ->where('RoleId','=',$role)
                           ->find_all();

       return $objects;
}
```

Проблема в том что если этого фильтра не будет существовать, я имею в виду фильтр `filters['Role']`, то естественно `ORM` ни вернет никаких объектов, как сделать так чтобы если этого фильтра нет, то наоборот, возвращались все объекты?

Comment: @xEdelweiss, нужно вернуть все записи в том случае если не один из фильтров не сработал, чего не происходит сейчас.

Comment: Что вам мешает?

    $objects = ORM::factory('object');
    if ($role) $objects->where('RoleId','=',$role);
    $objects = $objects->find_all();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из документации по [QueryBuilder'у](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/database/query/builder):

```
$query = DB::select()->from('users')->where('username', '=', 'john')->or_where('username', '=', 'jane');
```

Ключевой момент: [`or_where()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Database_Query_Builder_Select#or_where)

Comment: так же можете использовать для разных кострукций where_open() и where_close(), позволяет группировать условия

Comment: а если пользователь сделал поиск по чистым полям (должно все записи выбрать). Но как это программно будет?

Comment: Как напишете так и будет. Тот же ``LIKE '%%'`` вас никак не ограничит.

Comment: т.е. он опустит поиск по этому параметру вообще?

Comment: нет, он выполнит поиск, которому удовлетворят все записи - всё будет ровно так как вам хочется  
будет выглядеть, как будто поиска и не было

Comment: а если поля совсем пустые, а надо чтобы в таком случае выбрало все записи? ( я это логически выделил, вне `ORM` ), а так это не пропишешь в методичной выборке же.

Comment: я обновился, честно говоря не знаю, но тут `or_where` навряд ли прокатит, пробовал `where_open`, тоже смысла нет...

Comment: почему же не прокатит? для того он и ``or_where()``, что ``OR WHERE``